# List full name,salary and add column that subtract the old salary form the new salary. Label the column increase?

Tags: sql

List full name,salary  and add column that subtract the old salary form the new salary. Label the  column increase?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and tag the question with the database you are usig.

Answer (score 1):

You should know select ... from

```
select fullname, salary, salary - old_salary  as increase 
from my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is roughly as follows. You have to put the column headers in place of Name, Salary, New Salary and Old Salary. Then put your table name in place of "Your Table."

```
SELECT Name, Salary, SUM(New_Salary - Old_Salary) AS Increase
FROM Your_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

`select name,salary (newsalary-oldsalary) AS 'increase' from 'tablename';`